Error when build cross compiler libnfc to Aarch64 Android
I am trying to cross compile libnfc on Ubuntu 20.04 to Aarch64 Android 13 architecture via Ndk.
When I execute the make command I get the error:
ld.lld: error: --fix-cortex-a53-843419 is only supported on AArch64 targets
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
I need to be able to read contactless cards via chip on Android.
Has anyone ever done this, please give me the solution.

Unclear if you've seen: API documentation and limitation for NFC tags on Android and https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/nfc

Based on your prior question, I'm going to assume you've seen: https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/felica and related pages on that site.

I am unclear about your needs that why you need to use the libnfc instead of android's built-in NFC APIs.
But still answering your question: For reading contactless cards on Android, you have two alternatives:

Use Android's built-in NFC APIs instead of libnfc, which is better supported and doesn't require cross-compilation.
If you specifically need libnfc features, make sure to properly configure the build system to use Android's NDK toolchain with the correct target architecture flags but still using the custom library like libnfc in android for nfc is hard as its not easy to bypass the default built in NFC library.

export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
export TARGET=aarch64-linux-android
export API=21

export AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ar
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/clang
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/clang++
export LD=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/ld


When configuring the build, specify the correct target architecture:

./configure --host=$TARGET --target=$TARGET


Thank you for answering my question.
I just cross-compiled pcsclite and pushed it into the OEM circuit running Android 13 to support contact cards so I thought I'd do the same with contactless cards.
I did some research and found that libnfc supports that. If the NFC API has been integrated into the Android source, what do I need to do so that the chip on that circuit can communicate with contactless tags (of course they are contactless tags declared and supported in source)

Android devices use their own NFC controllers with specific drivers, and i think the standard libnfc library primarily supports NXP's NFC controller, which isn't typically used in Android devices and also bypassing Android's NFC stack requires system-level modifications and root access.
I appreciate your effort for trying to build custom implementation for NFC but don't think it's possible. I have wasted too much time with lifnfc android library in android with root access still i got timing issues led to failure to bypassing the default NFC API of android.

In your opinion if we integrate chip (for example NXP's PN7160) on our board and control it via I2C then is it possible to communicate with contactless card on Android. We work on Qualcomm system And I know it only supports a few lines of NFC tags and I need to integrate the types that qualcomm supports. I'm also new in this field so I want to hear from you.

If I use the existing Android NFC API, what do I need to do to enable it on the new module board? I mean setup a configuration file similar to reader.conf in libpcsclite, create an I2C port to communicate between CPU and IC card reader or other things so customers can call APIs and communicate with contactless cards.

I don't know where have you seen that you can directly communicate with CPU via I2C ( Even if that's possible then it will require Root access on android device for sure ) but still i am not able to understand that what you are trying to achieve. Sorry but i can't understand purpose of this question.
